# What to use in MySQL utf8mb4_unicode_ci or utf8_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql

the title says all the question.

I cannot find much information in google regarding what collation to use for my mysql database and all the tables.

Which one of those collations is better and why?
What about the character set utf8_unicode_ci vs utf8mb4_unicode_ci ?

Is there any risk or dissadvantage if I migrate all my old database (~=2015) from utf8_unicode_ci -> utf8mb4_unicode_ci charset and to utf8mb4 collate

Comment: Perhaps [check the docs?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html). `utf8_` is a synonym for `utf8mb3_` which is deprecated. `The utf8mb3 character set is deprecated and you should expect it to be removed in a future MySQL release. Please use utf8mb4 instead. `  Both `utf8mb3_` and `utf8mb4_` are UTF8 encodings. The difference is that one takes up to 3 bytes, the other up to 4, so it supports more characters.